# Proof of Reciprocal of Limits

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, proof-verification, convergence-divergence

I have tried to prove the following result, but looking around the internet and a few books, it always seems to be done differently - and I understand the variations I've seen. I would just like to know whether my argument below is logically correct or whether I have missed something out. It's been years since my Analysis modules at university and I'm afraid I'm a bit rusty at something I wasn't particularly great at at the time!

Thanks,

Andy.

**Proposition** (The Reciprocal Rule for Sequences)

If $(b_n)\rightarrow b$ and $b\neq 0$, then $\left(\frac{1}{b_n}\right)\rightarrow\frac{1}{b}$.

*Proof.*$\quad$
Suppose $b\neq 0$. Since $(b_n)\rightarrow b$, $(bb_n)\rightarrow b^2$. Because $\frac{b^2}{2}>0$ we can find a natural number $K_1$ such that $|bb_n - b^2|<\frac{b^2}{2}$ for all $n>K_1$. This is equivalent to
    \begin{equation*}
  b^2-\frac{b^2}{2} < bb_n < b^2+\frac{b^2}{2},
 \end{equation*}
    in particular $bb_n>\frac{b^2}{2}$, for all $n>K_1$. Next, we see that
    \begin{align*}
  \left| \frac{1}{b_n}-\frac{1}{b} \right| &= \left| \frac{b-b_n}{bb_n} \right|\\
  &< \left| \frac{b-b_n}{\frac{b^2}{2}} \right|\\
  &= \left|\frac{2}{b^2}\right||b-b_n|\\
  &= \frac{2}{b^2}|b-b_n|\\
 \end{align*}
    for all $n>K_1$. Let $\varepsilon>0$. Next, since $(b_n)\rightarrow b$, $(b_n-b)$ is a null sequence. So we can find a natural number $K_2$ such that $|b_n-b|<\frac{\varepsilon b^2}{2}$. Set $K=\max\{K_1,K_2\}$. Then
    \begin{equation*}
  \left| \frac{1}{b_n}-\frac{1}{b} \right| < \frac{2}{b^2}|b-b_n| < \frac{2}{b^2}\frac{\varepsilon b^2}{2} = \varepsilon
 \end{equation*}
    for all $n>K$. Therefore $\left(\frac{1}{b_n}-\frac{1}{b}\right)\rightarrow 0$ and, equivalently, $\left(\frac{1}{b_n}\right)\rightarrow\frac{1}{b}.$       QED

Comment: It might be less prone to confuse the reader if you take $K_1$ such that $n > K_1$ implies $b_n > \frac12b$ (this is, in effect, exactly how you chose $K_1$ in your proof, just in slightly different words). But the proof exactly as written in the question already looks complete to me.

Comment: Thank you for your advice David, that's great. :)